# Format decimal number

Tags: c#

I have decimal number always in US format, that is with decimal point.
But some countries have comma instead of decimal point.

This will format string in current culture:

```
   string.Format("{0:F2} {1}", 100.0018, '€')
```

Result is: 100,00 and it has comma instead of point as wanted.

Is there some function to format on so many decimal points as it is input value, in my case 100,0018?

I have tried with this:

```
Decimal.TryParse("100.0018", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out value);
```

but the result is 10000 instead of 100,0018

Comment: You need to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when parsing it if you *know* it will be using `.` as a decimal mark.

Comment: The "result" of `.Parse` is a number and _has no format_.  IT only has a format when you _display_ it, which is fully under your control. Are you saying that the _input_ is not parsing correctly or that you're seeing a different _output_?

Answer (score 1):

You, probably, want something like this:

```
 string.Format("{0:0.00###############} {1}", 100.0018, '€')
```

in order to have *at least* two digits after the decimal point:

```
100      -> 100.00 €      
100.0018 -> 100.0018 €
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
string.Format("{0:#,#.#####}", 100.0018)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NumberFormat`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var brazil = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        var usa = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        Console.WriteLine(100.0018m.ToString(brazil.NumberFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(100.0018m.ToString(usa.NumberFormat));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution vould be:
`string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:F2} {1}", 100.0018m, '€');`
Result: 100.00 €

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0:0.00###############} {1}", 100.0018, '€');
```

You can get the Currency by using `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture` also